# iBatis mapper binding exception with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mybatis, ibatis

I am experiencing this binding problem for iBatis. This is the structure of my project:

[image]

I am trying to map DeviceDao in Device.xml. This is how I did it in my Device.xml

```
<mapper namespace="service.dao.DeviceDao">
```

However, this error is thrown when I tried to access it.

```
"errorMessage": "Type interface service.dao.DeviceDao is not known to the MapperRegistry.","errorType": "org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException"
```

I tried changing it to smartcontrol.service.dao.DeviceDao but still didn't work.

What I don't understand is, why didn't the reference location of the Device 
object not cause any problem?

The device object that I am talking about is referenced in Configurations.xml

```
<typeAliases>  
    <typeAlias alias="Device" type="server.pojo.Device"/> 
</typeAliases>
```

Device is located under server.pojo

[image]

You see, they service.dao.DeviceDao and server.pojo.Device are both located under samples/src/main/java/smartcontrol. So, why is there a problem for referencing service.dao.DeviceDao, while no problem for server.pojo.Device??

Answer (score 0):

> "errorMessage": "Type interface service.dao.DeviceDao is not known to
>   the MapperRegistry.","errorType":
>   "org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException"

This means the mapper is not registered in the main MyBatis configuration file. More info: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers